# One liner ffmpeg (or other) to get only resolution?

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, regex, pipe

I'm not really well versed in the command line so hopefully this isn't too stupid of a question.

If I run:

```
ffmpeg -i videofile.avi
```

I get an output such as this:

```
ffmpeg version git-2013-11-21-6a7980e Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg develop    ers
  built on Nov 21 2013 12:06:32 with gcc 4.6 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
  configuration: --prefix=/home/user/ffmpeg_build --extra-cflags=-I/home/user/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/home/user/ffmpeg_build/lib --b        indir=/home/user/bin --extra-libs=-ldl --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable    -libfdk-    aac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-l    ibx264 --enable-    nonfree
  libavutil      52. 53.100 / 52. 53.100
  libavcodec     55. 44.100 / 55. 44.100
  libavformat    55. 21.100 / 55. 21.100
  libavdevice    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
  libavfilter     3. 91.100 /  3. 91.100
  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
  libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, avi, from 'videofile.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf52.68.0
  Duration: 00:23:07.68, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2390 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (XVID / 0x44495658), yuv420p, 640x480     [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 23.98 tbn, 1199 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (U[0][0][0] / 0x0055), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 k    b/s
```

If I were only interested in the command outputting "640x480", how might I do that?

I imagine I have to pipe the output to, and perform, a regular expression?  No idea how to do that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Get video resolution with ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i filename 2>&1 | grep -oP 'Stream .*, \K[0-9]+x[0-9]+'
```

Output (e.g.):

```
640x480
```

Comment: muru's answer was certainly more than sufficient, but this one specifically answers my question as asked (ie. using ffmpeg).  I don't know what the protocol here is with choosing an answer.  In this case, I think Muru's answer is more helpful while Cyrus's is more on point.  Sorry, not sure which way to go but right now I'm selecting Cyrus' as it is very specifically what I asked for (but I'm using Muru's  lol)

Comment: Be careful though. The example shown in the question would result in grep producing two matches (the first `0x44...` and the second being the resolution).

Comment: If the input contains multiple video streams, such as an input from a DVD, then this answer will output a `width x height` per video stream in multiple lines. This can be avoided if desired with `ffprobe`, or by adding `head -n 1` to the command in the answer.

Answer (score 12):

Using `ffprobe` from the ffmpeg package:

```
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=width,height -of csv=s=x:p=0 input.mp4
```

Example result:

```
1280x720
```

What these options do:

- `-v error` makes the output less verbose.
- `-select_streams v:0` selects only the first video stream.
- `-show_entries stream=width,height` chooses only `width` and `height` from the big list of parameters that `ffprobe` can provide.
- `-of csv=s=x:p=0` formats the text output. The `csv` formatting type is used because it makes a simple output. `s=x` makes it use an `x` to separate the `width` and `height` values. `p=0` makes it omit the `stream` prefix in the output.

See the [ffprobe documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html) and [FFmpeg Wiki: ffprobe tips](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FFprobeTips) for more info.

Comment: Thanks.  Wasn't aware of ffprobe.  So much help here!  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 5):

```
exiftool -b metavideo.mp4 -ImageWidth
exiftool -b metavideo.mp4 -ImageHeight
```

do the job without any `grep`s

One-liner looks like:

```
exiftool -b metavideo.mp4 -ImageSize
```

That returns WxH string that you was looking for.

Comment: This is not technically a one-liner.

Comment: I haven't noticed that it's one-liner requested, anyway doing the same width -ImageSize parameter returns WxH string.

Comment: Look at the title of the question again! ;-) Anyway +1

Answer (score 3):

I only see here samples of using `exiftool` and parsing it's output, which seems to be a weird choice. `exiftool` can be used in a direct manner to get the resolution (and almost any other metadata) :

`exiftool -ImageSize -s3 filename`

Will results in output in a form `WIDTHxHEIGHT` (eq: `1280×720`)

NOTE:
`-s3` instructs exiftool to produce the [shortest output format](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/exiftool_pod.html#s-NUM--short) (without tag names, quotes, etc)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using regular expressions and `ffmpeg`, but I'd prefer to use [`exiftool`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/exiftool.1p), part of the [libimage-exiftool-perl [image: Install libimage-exiftool-perl]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/libimage-exiftool-perl) package:

```
$ exiftool some/video.ogv | awk -F' *: *' '$1 == "Image Size"{print $2}'
1242x480
```

Why `exiftool`?

- The `ffmpeg`/`avprobe` utilities print lines of the form `Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (XVID / 0x44495658), yuv420p, 640x480` where one or more values of the form `AAAxBBB` are possible (as you can see in your example). Determining which one is the resolution might be difficult.
- `exiftool`, on the other hand, outputs data of the form `Type : Value`. So it's easier to get the exact field, namely `Image Size`. Plus, given the way the fields are specified (separated by colon and whitespace), you can easily extract the value.

What the [`awk`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/awk.1) command does is:

- Set the field separator to `' *: *'` - a colon `:` surrounded by any number of spaces.
- Check if the first field (`$1`) is `Image Size`
- And print the second field (`print $2`).

---

An alternate version would be:

```
awk '/^Image Size/{print $4}'
```

- By default, awk uses whitespace to split fields, so `Image`, `Size`, `:` and `1242x480` are all different fields.
- By matching the line's beginning (`^`) to `Image Size`, we get the correct line.
- And we print the fourth field (since `Image`, `Size` and `:` are the first three fields).

Comment: Thanks!  I might suggest you edit your example to change "Ubuntu_Free_Culture_Showcase/How\ fast.ogg" to something more generic.  At first I was using it literally because I didn't recognize it as a file name.  Of course, I saw my error 2 seconds later and your solution works great!

Comment: @bcsteeve I used it because it's part of the example content installed in Ubuntu desktop (see `/usr/share/example`). :D

Answer (score 2):

A slightly *esoteric* use of `mediainfo` will easily extract width and height in the format that you are after using a simple one-liner. Observe the following example on my system:

```
andrew@illium~$ mediainfo --Inform="Video;%Width%x%Height%" test.mp4
1920x1080
```

The various further parameters that can be used in this way can be seen with `mediainfo --Info-Parameters` but perhaps this simple usage by itself will suffice for you...

Answer (score 0):

I made a 1 liner `for` loop to extract resolution from directory of files.

```
for i in $(ls "/root/vidz/dollabillz/"*); do eval $(ffprobe -v error -of flat=s=_ -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=width,height "$i"); size=${streams_stream_0_width}x${streams_stream_0_height}; echo $i $size; done;
```

Comment: [Parsing `ls` will not end well](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)... quoting won't fix the mess

Comment: hasn't failed me yet after 100,000 encodes